# how to download ebi fastq link via command line using wget/curl

Tags: linux, osx, curl, wget, bioinformatics

I have loads of data (fastq) to download from ENA database.

```
Example: ERS076383 ERS012262 ERS160574 ERS349280 etc

Link to download via browser: 

https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/warehouse/filereport?accession=ERS076383&result=read_run&fields=fastq_ftp&download=txt
```

Now i would link to replace accession= one by one to download corresponding txt then i would use wget to download each ftp link that are associated with fastq. 
but I am unable to download it by wget.

```
i tried: 

wget https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/warehouse/filereport?accession=ERS076383&result=read_run&fields=fastq_ftp&download=txt
[1] 61380
[2] 61381
[3] 61382

Redirecting output to 'wget-log'....
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the url in quotes, like this:

```
wget 'https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/warehouse/filereport?accession=ERS076383&result=read_run&fields=fastq_ftp&download=txt'
```

or escape the ampersands (`\&`).

Comment: Thanks its working ....i use -O option to change the filename as it gives me very strange file name.